Expected number of factors of $LCM(1,…,n)$ (particularly, potentially, when $n=8t$)
I’m trying to prove something regarding $8t$-powersmooth numbers (a $k$-powersmooth number $n$ is one for which all prime powers $p^m$ such that $p^m|n$ are such that $p^m\le k$). Essentially, I have something I’m trying to prove for an arbitrary number $n$ expressed as $p^k t$ for $p^k$ maximal (in order to minimize $t$ to try to minimize the number of solutions). I know that when $n$ is $8t$-powersmooth, the number of solutions $p^k t$ to $p^k\le 8t$ is the number of positive divisors of (let $LCM(1,...,t)=L_t$ to save space) $L_{8t}$.
I know that $L_k\sim e^k$ so that  $L_{8t}\sim e^{8t}$, but it also seems to me a very poor number to treat as in some sense “normal” for the purposes of calculating number of divisors. This is because LCM will have unusually many high-degree small-prime factors and very few large-prime factors, leading to a greater number of factors overall. I’m just not sure whether there’s a known/explicit way to compensate for this higher-number-of-factors bias, so my question is as follows:

Roughly how many positive divisors does $L_t$ have, and in particular roughly how many positive divisors does $L_{8t}$ have?

Any pointers in the direction of relevant information would also be greatly appreciated.

your $L_t$  is close, in the sense of exponent for each prime, to the superior highly composite numbers. So you won't go far wrong using estimates (upper bounds)  for those.

Dissertation of G. Robin (1983):
With equality at $n = 6983776800 $ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$
With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$

We can just calculate it. Recall that if $m$ has prime factorization $m = \prod_p p^{e_p}$ (here the product ranges over primes $p$) then the number of divisors $d(m)$ satisfies
$$d(m) = \prod_p (e_p + 1).$$
It's not hard to see that the prime factorization of $L_n$ is $\prod p^{e_p}$ where $p^{e_p}$ is the largest power of $p$ less than or equal to $n$, which gives $e_p = \lfloor \log_p n \rfloor$. This gives
$$\boxed{ d(L_n) = \prod_p \left( \lfloor \log_p n \rfloor + 1 \right) }.$$
Here are some rough bounds on this quantity. The primes that appear in this product are exactly the primes $\le n$, and if $p$ is such a prime then $2 \le \lfloor \log_p n \rfloor + 1 \le \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor + 1$. Writing $\pi(n)$ for the number of such primes this gives simple upper and lower bounds
$$2^{\pi(n)} \le d(L_n) \le \left( \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor + 1 \right)^{\pi(n)}.$$
A more careful estimate could probably be obtained by splitting the product up into primes of various sizes, but this is already enough to tell us that $\ln d(L_n)$ grows somewhere between $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ and $\frac{n \ln \ln n}{\ln n}$, via the prime number theorem $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$. If you wanted to ask a more specific question to get a more specific bound that would be helpful; e.g. I don't know whether a lower or upper bound would be more useful for you.

Tuesday afternoon. As you can see in Qiaochu's answer, for   your $L$  the ratio of exponents  of prime factors $p,q$  is
$$ \frac{\log p}{\log q} $$
up to some "floor"  signs. Note that the exponents are non-increasing, the larger prime has the smaller exponent.
For a Superior Highly Composite number, small real parameter $\delta > 0$ the ratio of exponents is
$$ \frac{p^\delta - 1}{ q^\delta - 1}    $$
except for more "floor" signs.
The Taylor series with Lagrange remainder  says that this is
$$ \left( \frac{\log p}{\log q} \right) \left( \frac{2  + \delta p^{c_1} \log p}{2  + \delta q^{c_2} \log q} \right)   $$
which nears  $ \left( \frac{\log p}{\log q} \right)$ as $ \delta \longrightarrow 0^+ $
Tuesday morning: Dissertation of G. Robin (1983):
With equality at $n = 6983776800 $ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$
With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$
With equality at a number $n$ near $3.309 \cdot 10^{135},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log \log n} + \frac{4.762350121177...}{\left(\log \log n \right)^2} \right)}   $$
The above material is in a 1988 survey article by Jean-Louis Nicolas
I've been running a simulation; I  recommend the estimate (all natural logarithms)
$$   d \approx L^{ \left(1 + \frac{1.9}{\log \log L}  \right) \left( \frac{ \log 2}{\log \log L}  \right)} $$
As I commented earlier, your $L$ numbers are not much worse than Ramanujan's Superior Highly Composite Numbers as far as large divisor count.
Mon 17 Jun 2024 09:36:25 PM PDT

n    LCM   Div     coeff        ln(LCM)
2    2     2     0.560313     0.693147 
3    6     4     -0.203549     1.79176 
4    12     6     -0.0483461     2.48491 
5    60     12     0.33018     4.09434 
7    420     24     0.656689     6.04025 
8    840     32     0.793602     6.7334 
9    2520     48     0.962638     7.83201 
11    27720     96     1.15521     10.2299 
13    360360     192     1.30283     12.7949 
16    720720     240     1.36651     13.488 
17    12252240     480     1.46302     16.3212 
19    232792560     960     1.54201     19.2657 
23    5354228880     1920     1.59745     22.4012 
25    26771144400     2880     1.65688     24.0106 
27    80313433200     3840     1.70339     25.1092 
29    2329089562800     7680     1.73469     28.4765 
31    72201776446800     15360     1.76326     31.9105 
32    144403552893600     18432     1.79229     32.6036 
37    5342931457063200     36864     1.80762     36.2146 
41    219060189739591200     73728     1.81839     39.9281 
43    9419588158802421600     147456     1.82964     43.6893 
47    442720643463713815200     294912     1.83778     47.5395 
49    3099044504245996706400     442368     1.86785     49.4854 
53    164249358725037825439200     884736     1.87169     53.4557 
59    9690712164777231700912800     1769472     1.87168     57.5332 
61    591133442051411133755680800     3538944     1.87308     61.6441 
64    1182266884102822267511361600     4128768     1.88838     62.3372 
67    79211881234889091923261227200     8257536     1.88707     66.5419 
71    5624043567677125526551547131200     16515072     1.88536     70.8046 
73    410555180440430163438262940577600     33030144     1.88495     75.0951 
79    32433859254793982911622772305630400     66060288     1.88273     79.4645 
81    97301577764381948734868316916891200     82575360     1.89944     80.5631
 n                  LCM                          Div        coeff       ln(LCM)

